# Ubuntu 13.04: Steam, Dualshock3

Tags: 13.04, steam, gamepad, ps3

I want Ubuntu to recognize my PS3 Dualshock3 controller so i can use it with my steam games.

How can I do this? Keep in mind I'm very new to Ubuntu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start steam, switch to "big Picture" go to Settings and click on Gamepad ...

The rest is self-explanatory and have Fun ;)

Greetings

Lupopa

Comment: Thanks that worked. Much easier fix than all the crazy terminal based solutions I was finding. Thank you.

Comment: one problem I found is the sensitivity of the analogs. When not used they would still issue directional commands.